# chromatic number in a "duo-planar graph"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

For the purposes of this task, we will call a "duo-planar" graph, a graph that has been made of joined two planar graphs. More precisely, G is duo-planar, when $E(G)$ can be divided into two sets $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$, that $E(G)=E_{1} \cup E_{2}$, and graphs $(V(G),E1)$ i $(V(G),E2)$ are planar. Let $kol_{min}$ be the largest chromatic number among chromatic numbers of duo-planar graphs. Estimate as best as you can from above and below $kol_{min}$.

I really have no idea how to do that. I will appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Perhaps look at complete graphs to obtain some early bounds and then try and improve on them from there. For example it is easy to see $kol_{min} \geq 6$ since $K_{6}$ is duo-planar. However $K_{11}$ is not duo-planar as it has too many edges to be separated into two planar graphs.

Comment: How did you conclude that $K_{11}$ has to many edges ?

Comment: For all graphs $G$ with $n$ vertices, $n >2$, if $G$ is planar $G$ has at most $3(n-2)$ edges. This follows from Eulers Formula. See the wikipedia page for planar graphs if you are still unconvinced. Now since we are working with duo-planar graphs, each separation can have at most $3(n-2)$ edges, so our graph $G$ can have at most $6(n-2)$ edges.  Now a complete graph has $\frac{(n)(n-1)}{2}$ edges. Solving $\frac{(n)(n-1)}{2} > 6(n-2)$ gives $11$ as a bound.